subprocess stdin не выполняет команды
имеется такой код:
command = ['java', '-Xmx6G', '-Xms1024M', '-jar', 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860.jar', "nogui"]
mmmd = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


def a():
    while True:
        print(mmmd.stdout.readline().decode())
        time.sleep(0.01)

def b():
    while True:
        a = input()
        mmmd.stdin.write(a.encode())
        print(mmmd.stdout.readline().decode())


t1 = Thread(target=a)
t1.start()

t2 = Thread(target=b)
t2.start()

Когда я посылаю команду ничего не происходит. Как быть?

Так у вас только a по идее запустится и будет вечно крутиться, до b ход не дойдёт. Хотя если поток с a упадёт после того как вывод из субпроцесса весь кончится... Как-то это всё не очень выглядит.

Вы сейчас создаете первый тред, потом ждете его завершения через join. Он никогда не завершается, поэтому второй тред никогда не запускается. Просто не делайте джойны.

@insolor убрал join но это не помогло

Прежде всего непонятно - зачем вам вообще тут два потока?

один поток выводит вывод, а второй для ввода команд
